# How does Android kernel receive from cellular network packet?

Tags: android, networking, linux-kernel, cellular-network

I'm wondering which hardware component on the mobile device is responsible for receiving the cellular network packet and then interrupting the Android kernel to handle the packet?

Also, which Android kernel function is responsible for handling the incoming cellular network packets?

Any explanation or related document is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @SWan Cell phone data is controlled on another processor.  There is a software component that interfaces with that processor.

Comment: @PeterL. could you please be more specific about what's the software component in Android kernel?

Comment: @SWan It has been years since I've worked on mobile platform system software, but a typical architecture will separate major subsystems into different processors.  The subsystem that handles cell network packets is the 'modem'.  Data between processors is marshalled via RPC or other mechanisms.  This (Qualcomm) image illustrates a high level archtecture:  https://eda360insider.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/qualcomm-snapdragon-4-block-diagram.jpg

Comment: @PeterL Thanks! The figure does provide some information I'm looking for.